# Meaning of "ADM: not assigned, Under Review" for IEEE Access

Tags: peer-review, journals, ieee, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to IEEE Access (at the website : https://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/ieee-access)

This is a re-submission revised according to reviews (all were accept with minor edits). On the journal’s home page I can see that EIC has been assigned but, the ADM has not been assigned. It also states: "Under Review".

Does this mean my manuscript has been sent to the reviewers OR, does nothing happen until the ADM has been assigned? In the official IEEE Access webpage for 'Stages of Peer Review', I can see nothing about the ADM.

Though there are similar questions, they seem to be for other specific journals.

Comment: Isn't ADM the admin person?  I believe the system has directly sent your article to the same reviewers for confirmation, and after that, the handling editor will be emailed to make a decision.  In general, you shouldn't be looking at every little change in your status.  The system works.  Just 'forget' about it for now, and if there are problems, they will email you!

Comment: @fac120  Same situation here. Any update from your submission?

Comment: @lenhhoxung My experience is only with IEEE Access and I can only speak from experience and by guessing. I am not sure if I am correct.
anyway, I think the review process did not begin before the ADM had been assigned. Because, on the day the ADM was assigned, we received an email like - "Dear ABC, We have started the review process for your article, but wanted to mention the '2021 IEEE Access Best Video Award Part 1'".
This makes me think the process was started after the ADM was assigned. We received decision around one month later.